# symfony 2.6 to 2.8 issues

Tags: symfony

I'm upgrading my app from 2.6 straight to 2.8. I got the following error on a choicelist form:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to xxxxx::__construct() must
>   be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface,
>   instance of Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList given

I don't know if this is related to this note of deprecation:

> "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface
>   was deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 3.0. You should use
>   Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface instead"

If I switch this, I get:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to render the form because the block names array contains
>   duplicates: "_wizard_page_type_blocks_entry_answers_entry_value_row",
>   "entity_row", "entity_row", "choice_row", "form_row".") in
>   form_div_layout.html.twig

Can you help me out?

---

EDIT:
just found out that, when this was working (sf 2.6) that argument was an instance of `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList`
it's now (sf 2.7) an instance of `Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList`

Comment: Try to upgrade from 2.6 to 2.7 then 2.7 to 2.8. There's a specific guide for each versio upgrade. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.7.md

Comment: Trying, now in 2.7 still getting the same error. Still troubleshooting.

Comment: Had you already made changes before moving to 2.7?  If so then maybe revert everything.  Symfony downs a good job of maintaining backwards compatibility.  The 2.8 form component is a bit of an anomaly but even there I would expect your 2.6 code to work.  You are sure the code works under 2.6 right?

Comment: I'm sure it works, but I'm not sure is 100% correct ;-) Still investigating. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: @andregoncalves you ever get an answer on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should change a type hinting for a constructor of your class `xxxxx`

Instead of

`\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface`

it's now

`\Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface`

(probably must be change in `use`)

Comment: After doing that, I get `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to render the form because the block names array contains duplicates: "_wizard_page_row", "entity_row", "entity_row", "choice_row", "form_row".") in form_div_layout.html.twig`

Comment: So check your `form_div_layout.html.twig` and remove duplicating blocks